# My bicycle's rear wheel is wobbling

Tags: freewheel, wobble

I have a fat bike (Giant Momentum Iride Rocker 3). It says this bike didn't design for offroading but I have one bike and I use it on single-tracks (not very technical) and doing long trips (about 75kms per day). I usually have heavy luggage. But nowadays, the rear wheel is wobbling side to side (when you look the bike from the behind it wobbles right and left, I mean the top of the wheel wobbles to the chain and to the kickstand. I hope you understand.) And it does this freely, sometimes to right; sometimes to left. So I don't think the wheel is out of trueing. Can you suggest me what to do? Because I don't trust the local bike shop he is trying to sell new parts and usually lies about broken parts. If you need more information I can share with you. And I'm sorry for my bad English. The bicycle has a freewheel by the way, not a cassette.

Comment: Either the the wheel is out of true or the bearings are loose.  With the wheel off the ground, grab it at the edge and move it back and forth.  If it moves more than a very little bit then the bearings need service.

Comment: Check the "related" links on the right - read through them and find which ones describe your bike.  You need to figure out where the play is, in the bearings or in the dropouts or in the rim, or even in the tyre fit.   All possibles.   These have all been asked before.